# Python 3.6 Bittrex API INVALID_SIGNATURE

Tags: php, python-3.x

I am not a developer by trade, so please go easy on me.

I have been working on a Bittrex API as a way of teaching myself Python and API's. I managed to get it working in PHP with a lot of Stack Overflow searches before switching to Python 3.6. Now I am stuck again on a portion that requires hashing and signatures.

My functional PHP code:

```
<?php

$apikey='...';
$apisecret='...';
$nonce=time();
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalance? 
$apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce.'&currency=BTC';
$sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$data=curl_exec($ch);

echo $data      

?>
```

Python equivalent:

```
import urllib.request
import json
import collections
import time
import hashlib
import hmac
nonce = str('{:10.0f}'.format(time.time()))
apikey = '...'
apisecret = '...'
BaseCurrency = 'BTC'
url = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalance? 
apikey='+apikey+'&nonce='+nonce+'&currency='+BaseCurrency
sign = hmac.new(b'apisecret', b'url', hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={"apisign" : sign})
balance = json.load(urllib.request.urlopen(request))

print(balance)
```

This returns {'success': False, 'message': 'INVALID_SIGNATURE', 'result': None}.

I have spent a couple days on this and have not been able to get passed it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use

```
apikey = b'...'
apisecret = b'...'
```

instead of

```
apikey = '...'
apisecret = '...'
```

and

```
sign = hmac.new(apisecret, url, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
```

instead of

```
sign = hmac.new(b'apisecret', b'url', hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite old but I struggled a bit before handling the connexion, here is my code :

```
api_secret='...'
api_key='...'
url='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalances?apikey='+api_key+'&nonce='+str(time.time())
sign=hmac.new(bytes(api_secret,encoding='utf-8'),bytes(url,encoding='utf-8'),hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()


req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={"apisign" : sign})
account=urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
account_j=json.loads(account)

print(account_j)
```

I had to read() the request once opened so that the json was correctly handled.